# What is closer to python None: nil or NULL?

Tags: python, objective-c

What value in objective-C would be more close to the value of `None` in python?

```
python: x = None

1) 
obj-C: id x = nil;

2) 
obj-C: id x = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` is used for non-object pointers; `void *`. And `nil` is used in place of an id. Nil can be used anywhere where you can use NULL. So it would be `nil` in my opinion as `None` in Python represent the absence of a value

> NULL (void *)0 literal null value for C pointers
>
> nil (id)0 literal null value for Objective-C objects