# No results calling find_all for text in a specific class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the text for a specific class, but it is returning an empty list:

```
>>> soup.find_all(' dataRow odd')
[]
```

html:

```
<tr class=" dataRow odd" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" 
onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" 
onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class='actionColumn'>&nbsp;</td><th scope="row" class=" dataCell  ">
<a href="/a0I9000000hHJIN?btdid=0019000001piFE9">textexttext</a></th><td class=" dataCell  ">Active</td><td class=" dataCell  ">
<a href="/a089000001nOvG8?btdid=0019000001piFE9">BIG TEXT/a></td>
<td class=" dataCell  ">TEXTTEXTTEXT</td><td class=" dataCell  ">TEXTTEXTTEXT</td>
<td class=" dataCell  "> </td><td class=" dataCell  ">&nbsp;</td><td class=" dataCell  DateElement">8/02/2019</td></tr>
```

I'm trying to grab ALL text within that code.
But when I run my code it returns `[]` as if it didn't find anything.

```
import requests, bs4, re
html = open('2.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile, "lxml")
duh = soup .find_all(' dataRow odd')
print (duh)
```

Where am I going wrong?
Also, ideally the code would spit out all the separate text on different lines

Comment: I believe your `findAll()` is being given the wrong argument. You would need to `findAll('tr', {"class": ' dataRow odd'})`. As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class) question.

Comment: Thanks,

Problem is it now spits out the entire code. I'm trying to isolate just the text and print it just from the text

Comment: Python doesn't have `nil`. See [Ruby use case for nil, equivalent to Python None or JavaScript undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884004/ruby-use-case-for-nil-equivalent-to-python-none-or-javascript-undefined) and [What is closer to python None: nil or NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498810/what-is-closer-to-python-none-nil-or-null)

Comment: RTFM before asking. bs4 manual is straightforward

Comment: Hi yeah have read the manual, still need help, thanks anyway.

Yes, I meant none.
it prints as []

Answer (score 0):

Querying for `dataRow odd` yields the surrounding `<tr>` which includes all other elements within, `<td>` and `<a>` etc. You can grab *just the text* by accessing the `.text` property like so, it will give you just a big blob of text instead of HTML:

```
for d in duh:
    print d.text
```

Instead of that, you can fetch all `<td>` elements within that `<tr>` separately, and grab the `.text` from each individual element.

```
import requests, bs4, re

html = open('test.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") # use html parser instead of XML
duh = soup.find_all('tr', {'class':' dataRow odd'}) # using ktb's suggestion from comments
for d in duh:
    tds = d.find_all()
    for td in tds:
        cleaned = td.text.strip().rstrip('\n') # remove newlines and spaces
        if cleaned != '':
            print cleaned
```